# pi locked out after trying to autorun a script

Tags: raspbian

I was playing with the autorun functionality of pi and was trying to run a c++ code but it got stuck after i tried to reboot my pi. now I'm getting this screen and now im unable to log in.. i have tried with pi and raspberry as login and password but unable to log in[image]

Comment: Have you tried shift+alt+f1 or ctrl+alt+f1 to get a console prompt?

Comment: thanx i got the console back.. but now after entering my id and password it says time out in login authority i guess thats what it said coz it blanked out in a minute.. nothing on the screen now.. can you help?

Comment: i did ctrl+alt+F1 again and now the screen says "No protocol specified" continuously!!

Comment: I can't help with that.  Do you have another Linux machine you can use to edit the files on the SD card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to boot in [single user mode](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=109612) where you don't need the password and then use: **passwd root** (or username) to change password.

Of course if the password is the problem.